# Use Ember.NoneLocation while still using Router to deserialize in UIWebView

Tags: ember.js

I have a Router that looks like this:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  root: Em.Route.extend({
    index: Em.Route.extend({
      route:'/',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context){
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('textChallenge', App.TextChallenge.find());
      }
    }),

    textChallenge: Em.Route.extend({
      route:'/textChallenge/:challengeId',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context){
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('textChallenge', context);
      },
      //this doesn't really work yet
      serialize: function(router, context){
        return{
          challengeId: context.get('challengeId')
        }
      },
      deserialize: function(router, urlParams){
        return App.TextChallenge.find(urlParams.challengeId);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

However, I am trying to run this in UIWebView and it doesn't like the URLs to be messed with (see this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1575). I just don't quite understand how to implement Ember.NoneLocation here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it as simple as setting a property on the router `location: 'none'`

Comment: So would that be set per route? Or for the entire Router object? And hey, thanks for meeting me over here after responding to my ticket :) I believe I owe you a beer at this point.

Comment: It would be global for the router object. I'd recommend reading the source code for Router, and each of the Location implementations. It will help you understand how this all works. And, no problem. I like Belgian brews. :-)

Comment: Hm, looks like I am misunderstanding something about how this works. Is it possible to set this at the router level but still have it deserialize URLs? I like Belgians too :)

Comment: OK, last question. The source is somewhat helpful, but I can't understand it well enough to answer this question: is it possible to set location: 'none' and have the router function (serialize & deserialize)? It doesn't seem to work. I think I need to move this over to IRC and have a talk about the basic nature of the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps not, since there is nothing to serialize and deserialize to. But I'm not sure why you would need to if you have no URL. Is it that you need to support URL on initial launch?

Comment: location: 'none' is not enough.